# MS-SQL: How to use the 'current' sequence value multiple times

Tags: sql-server

```
T_Table
+-----+-----+------+------+------+-----------
| XID | aid | amin | amax | aavg | bid...
+-----+-----+------+------+------+-----------

T_Table_A
+-----+---+---+
| aid | x | y |
+-----+---+---+

T_Table_B
+-----+---+---+
| bid | t | v |
+-----+---+---+
```

Given the *simplified* table structure above, I want to insert data into `T_Table` and detailed data into `T_Table_A` and `T_Table_B`. The ID for `T_Table` is generated before we reach this point, but the IDs for Table_A and Table_B are not. I was planning to use a `SEQUENCE` for this and it works. *But its... not really... readable. Might be the wrong wording, I am just hoping there is a "better" way*. The "problem" with the `SEQUENCE` value is that it can be read only once (yes, I could query `sys.sequences` but that imho adds even more complexity) but needs to be used multiple times. So I ended up by declaring a variable, assigning the sequence value and using the variable in the insert statements.

```
-- Transaction started in program code
DECLARE @var AS INT;
SELECT @var = (NEXT VALUE FROM schema.SEQ_Name)
INSERT INTO T_Table VALUES(1, @var, 67, 184, 143, @var, ...)
INSERT INTO T_Table_A(@var, 0, 75)
INSERT INTO T_Table_A(@var, 1, 75)
INSERT INTO T_Table_A(@var, 2, 74)
...
INSERT INTO T_Table_B(@var,  0, 67)
INSERT INTO T_Table_B(@var,  5, 68)
INSERT INTO T_Table_B(@var, 10, 72)
-- commit/rollback transaction
```

Is this the right approach to use a generated sequence number multiple times (multiple times)?

*Would be great if we dont need to talk about the structure, i can't change it anyway :)*

Comment: Where are you getting all these `INSERT` statements from?

Comment: you mean the data to be inserted? they are read from a file. the hole thing is part of a software based process that imports data from the filesystem (files placed in a specific folder) to the database by reading the file, parsing the content and generating insert statements from the content read @Charlieface

Comment: There's nothing that wrong with the above code as such, just that it sounds like you should be using some kind of bulk insert mechanism instead. What you have will be very slow with a lot of rows.

Comment: I would urge you to specify your columns when writing insert statements. Assuming all the columns are static can cause issues.

Comment: "...Is this the right approach..." There really is no way to answer this question for multiple reasons. Firstly, "right" needs context and there is none. Does it work correctly? Then you can conclude it is "right". Given your first INSERT statements uses `@var` twice, it has a bad smell. In addition, your code is fragmentary and "theoretical" which can be misleading to the reader. The search for "better way" is also a meaningless question without context. "Better" has no particular measure.

Comment: @SeanLange thats only part of the example so i had to write less. sorry :/

Comment: @Charlieface thats a really good hint for performance, its indeed very slow if the resolution of the data is high or the duration long. i probably won't be able to modify existing parsers but thats something i can do for new ones i am creating.

Comment: Well, I met this system the day I joined the company. They currently are using `char[24]` keys for `T_TableX` - that means the key is larger then the actual data. Thats the reason why I want to change it to numeric for newly created parsers. They are also using the same char-key for `T_TableA` and `T_TableB` and since both tables are only bound to exactly `T_Table` I think its legal to do so. And thats the reason why I would use the same sequence-number too. @SMor